# AngularJS Directive and jQuery DOM Event Binding

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

i've created a directive and i'm not quite sure about the binding like `element.bind("click", function(){})`. The link function of each directive gets called multiple times and each call will produce a duplicate binding. What is the most Angular way to accomplish this (even the click binding is available as attribute)  ?

```
var globalCounter = 0;
app.directive("myDirective", function()
{
    return {
       link: function(scope, element) {
          globalCounter++;
          $(element).bind("click", function () {});
       }
    }
});
```

The globalCounter variable (and the click bindings ?) will increase every time i change the ng-view to a different template.

Maybe the element gets destroyed and the binding with it, i'm not sure, maybe this is my answer.

Comment: pls post fiddle or plunker of demo you have tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumption are not completely correct. The directive link function gets invoked once per directive declaration. So the element on which click is getting attached is different. Therefore each function is acting on a different control.

You can still do css selector based click action binding, but then the directive should be defined on the parent.

Also when the view changes the DOM is destroyed and hence you old binding will get removed.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can set a restrict config option

> First, we’re setting the restrict config option. The restrict option
>   is used to specify how a directive can be invoked on the page.
>
> As we saw before, there are four different ways to invoke a directive,
>   so there are four valid options for restrict:
>
> ```
> 'A' - <span ng-sparkline></span>
> 'E' - <ng-sparkline></ng-sparkline>
> 'C' - <span class="ng-sparkline"></span>
> 'M' - <!-- directive: ng-sparkline -->
> ```

http://www.ng-newsletter.com/posts/directives.html

Comment: Just left this to make this example more simple.

Answer (score 1):

You did not put the counter in the click event. Also, you do not need jQuery selector for the element that has the directive.

```
app.directive("myDirective", function()
{
    return {
       link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
          element.bind("click", function () {
             // Click event here
          });
       }
    }
});
```

Comment: its still the same problem. The link function gets called multible time. Each time a new bind is done to the element...

Comment: How are you binding it to the element? Can you show the HTML snippet containing the directive?

Answer (score 0):

i wrote little example of this derective https://github.com/JTOne123/angularJs.elementReady/blob/master/src/onElementReady.js
and fix here some problems with scope